# I'm needing help understanding this coding theory assignment

Tags: computer-science, coding-theory

I'm needing help understanding how to approach this assignment.

- Create a code consisting of binary codewords.
- The code must meet three requirements
  -- Contain at least 20 codewords
  -- Have a minimum distance of 3 (explain why a min distance of 4 is no better than 3)
  -- Maintain efficiency by using the fewest number of bits per codeword as possible
- Clearly document and describe your code: what it is, why you chose it, etc.

I understand the concept of a codeword in that it encodes data into 'bits' of information. For example, the set {A,B,C,D} can be encoded as {01,11,00,10} and we can use the nearest neighbor algorithm to 'change' any n-tuple received into its correct encoding. I don't understand how to encode 20 'codewords'. Do I simply take all possible permutations of {101010} which are,

- {111000 110100 110010 110001 101100 101010 101001 100110 100101 100011 011100 011010 011001 010110 010101 010011 001110 001101 001011 000111}

I'm quite confused with how to approach this assignment.

Comment: The two first words in your list are at Hamming distance two from each other only, so that won't do. You need longer sequences. My mind is so linear that I need words of 9 bits, but then my code contains 32 codewords. Not sure whether a more twisted mind can get away with strings of length 8.

Comment: But, may guess is that a linear construction will do nicely. Has the concept of shortening a code been explained in your course?

Comment: "a min distance of 4 is no better than 3" is false. (it's true only in relation with error correction -and in some respect- but not with error detection). Anyway, such an assignment assumes (I guess) that you have studied before some theory about linear codes